# Define a (lattice) Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$ v.s. $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, yang-mills-theory

Pure Yang-Mills theory (YM) can be easily defined on $\mathbb{T}^4$ on a periodic lattice, using the [Wilson lattice gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_gauge_theory) approach. In reality, we know some of these mathematical results on $\mathbb{T}^4$, e.g. See [T. Bałaban works in Comm Math Physics](https://projecteuclid.org/search_result?type=index&q.a.author=T.%20Ba%C5%82aban) and also [the descriptions and citations given in the claymath.org note](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/yangmills.pdf).

> So what makes the difference to define a lattice Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$ v.s. $\mathbb{R}^4$?

- Define a lattice Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$ is easily doable since a $\mathbb{T}^4$ can have a finite length $L$, given the lattice constant $a$, there are about $(L/a)^4$ lattice links. 
  In some sense, define a lattice Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$
  then taking the continuum limit (view the lattice constant $a$ to be small), also define a continuum Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$. 
  Most people believe that all the properties will carry over from the discrete to the continuum limit.
- Define a lattice Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{R}^4$ seems harder, since the length of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite $L_\mathbb{R}=\infty$, so there are about $(L_\mathbb{R}/a)^4\to \infty$ infinite lattice links.

> However, the pure Yang-Mills theory should have the same property and the same mass gap for a large size $\mathbb{T}^4$ as good as $\mathbb{R}^4$ (is it correct?). If so, what makes the big deal difference to define lattice Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$ v.s. $\mathbb{R}^4$? (It shall be a trivially gapped TQFT with a mass gap.)

- Add: The topology of $\mathbb{T}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ is obviously different from each other. I am asking that why not just defines YM on $\mathbb{T}^4$ (at least on the lattice), which seems to be much tractable but captures every property we wanted for YM on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: "Easily defined"?   The $a \to 0$ limit of lattice Yang-Mills  $\mathbb{T}^4$ is very hard to construct - see Magnen's paper "[Construction of YM4 with an infrared cutoff](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104253284)".

Comment: My understanding is that for lattice gauge theory, the ultraviolet high energy, short distance cutoff does not concern us - it is set by the $a$, as long as the number of lattice sites is finite.  My point is that the number of lattice sites is finite on $T^4$ but not on $R^4$, so why do we bother $R^4$ if every property (?) is the same in terms of physical observables?

Comment: I think the confusion is coming from your use of "on a lattice on T^4" instead of "on Z/n^4"  which limits to what John was thinking of as n goes to infinity.

Comment: The topology of $\mathbb{T}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ is obviously different from each other. I am asking that why not just defines YM on $\mathbb{T}^4$, which seems to be much tractable but captures every property we wanted for YM on  $\mathbb{R}^4$ (yes?).

Comment: Sure, go ahead and "just" define Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$.   That would be very nice. You'd become famous - it's a famously difficult problem.  If the expected values of physical quantities keep changing a lot as you increase the size of the $\mathbb{T}^4$, it will not have a theory on $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a limit and people will be disappointed - but still, getting a $\mathbb{T}^4$ theory would be a huge advance.

Comment: @John Baez, thank you. for a pure YM (without the topological $\theta$-term), there is only one ground state on $T^4$, and the only energy scale is the mass gap. There is no other observable on $T^4$. This is the similar situation also on $R^4$.  There is only one ground state on $R^4$, and the only energy scale is the mass gap. You agree or not?

Comment: I agree except for your claim that there is no other observable for Yang-Mills theory on $\mathbb{T}^4$.   You seem to be using the word "observable" in a strange way.

Comment: For pure Yang-Mills, there are only glueballs (as some excited states), this shall relate to the mass gap energy scale. There are *no* other TQFTs (causing dimensions of Hilbert space $dim \mathcal{H}$ >1, such as no dynamical BF theory etc). This applies to $T^4$ or $R^4$ if I am not mistaken.